# Android: why this AsyncTask does not not get executed....?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have this code,

that is supposed to CALL and WAIT the

AsyncTask **"getCreator"**.

---

```
private String getcreator(String id) {
        String creator = null;
        Log.e("","entro proprio in getcreator "+ id);
        if (id != null) {
            String srt = "";
            getCreator chn = new getCreator();
            chn.execute(id, null, null);
            try {
                srt = chn.get();
                Log.e("","predodo qulacosa da getcreator");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("","exceltion in getcreator");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            JSONObject jObject = null;
            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(srt);
                creator = jObject.getString("name");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // Json parse error usually
            }
        }
        return creator;
    }
```

---

But the AsyncTask **getCreator** never performs its doinbackground() !!!

---

```
    public class getCreator extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        public String res;

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... symbol) {
            String result = "";
            Log.e("","entro in getcreator"+ symbol[0]);
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is
            // established.
            // The default value is zero, that means the timeout is not
            // used.
            int timeoutConnection = 3000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,
                    timeoutConnection);
            // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT)
            // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
            int timeoutSocket = 5000;
            HttpConnectionParams
            .setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
            client.setParams(httpParameters);
            String srt = "";
            String url = "http://graph.facebook.com/".concat(symbol[0]);
            HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet(url);
            try {
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                srt = client.execute(getMethod, responseHandler);

                result = srt;

            } catch (Throwable t) {
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                // "Internet Problem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            Log.e("","esco in getcreator");
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Please HELP!!!!

---

TO BE PRECISE:
**doInBackground() does not even get executed....**

the method private String getcreator(String id) is called regularly, and produces its Log.

help!!!

Comment: post your logcat. what do you see in the log? do you see this `Log.e("","entro in getcreator"+ symbol[0])` log message?

Comment: @Raghunandan Hi Raghunandan, I do not see "entro in getcreator"... so doInBackground is not even started....

Comment: is your asynctask an inner class of your activity class where you invoke the asycntask by calling execute?

Comment: @Raghunandan yes Raghunandan, that is precisely the case! You are a genius !!!! How do I solve this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling the `get()` method of `AsyncTask` will block the main thread and wait for the result to be returned. This effectively makes using an AsyncTask become a synchronous operation in which case there's no point in using an AsyncTask.

The only reason I can think of to use the `get()` method would be from a thread other than the main (UI) thread although I can't think of many reasons to do that.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

You can return the result in `doInbackground`. The result of `doInBackground()` computation is a parameter to `onPostExecute`.

Since your asynctask is a inner class of your activity. You can declare  `String create` as  your activity class variable and use the same.

```
private String getcreator(String id) {
 if(id!=null) // make sure id is not null
 { 
 GetCreator chn = new GetCreator();
 chn.execute(id); 
 // call execute to invoke asynctask
 // there is no need to pass null
 // pass the id to doInBackground()  
 }
}
```

AsyncTask

```
public class GetCreator extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    public String res;

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
     if(result!=null)
     {
        JSONObject jObject = null;
        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(result);
            creator = jObject.getString("name");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // Json parse error usually
            e.printStacktace(); 
        }
     }  
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... symbol) {
        String result = "";
        Log.e("","entro in getcreator"+ symbol[0]);
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is
        // established.
        // The default value is zero, that means the timeout is not
        // used.
        int timeoutConnection = 3000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,
                timeoutConnection);
        // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT)
        // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
        int timeoutSocket = 5000;
        HttpConnectionParams
        .setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
        client.setParams(httpParameters);
        String srt = "";
        String url = "http://graph.facebook.com/".concat(symbol[0]);
        HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet(url);
        try {
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            srt = client.execute(getMethod, responseHandler);

            result = srt;

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            // "Internet Problem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        Log.e("","esco in getcreator");
        return result; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What the log say? Where the getcreator(String id) method is called?

(Cosa leggi nei log? Il metodo getcreator(String id) dove viene richiamato?)

---

[ - Waiting for the OP - ]

You're getting it wrong. You don't have to "get" something from the AsyncTask.

```
srt = chn.get();
```

The AsycnTask is performing an asynchronous task, so you start it and that's it. The "update" is all upon the task, in the onPostExecute().

**(as the comments pointed out you can do this, but it's "bad")**

First of all, these three parameters in the constructor `chn.execute(id, null, null)` are not the one on top `AsyncTask<String, String, String>`. They're the parameters you get in the `doInBackground(String... symbol)`. So `symbol[0]` is `id`, and `symbol[1]` and `symbol[2]` are null

And just for knowloedge's sake:

```
Log.e -> ERROR
Log.d -> DEBUG
Log.i -> INFO
```

You're actually "debugging", so you should use Log.d

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. According to the documentation, `get()` should wait until the task completes and return the result. I agree that using `get()` here is bad, but it should still work.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `new getCreator().execute(id, "", "");` 
and in `onPostExecute` write " `Log.i("","post execute");` "
After post the log cat

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the design of your method `getcreator()` is wrong.

The `AsyncTask` will be executed asynchronously, but your first thread (UI Thread?) will be waiting for the result.
`AsyncTask` is useless in this case.

You should probably update your UI (or do whatever you want with the result) in the `onPostExecute()` method of your `AsyncTask`, without blocking the first thread.